# How to pass PHP variables to a new HTML page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I need to draw a simple triangle with some values passed trough a PHP file. To be more specific, I need to:

1. Create a HTML document who has a form that calls a php file.
2. Inside the PHP file the values of the form will be obtained as PHP variables.
3. Then, PHP will open another HTML document.
4. Inside the new HTML document, PHP variables will be catched and used to draw a triangle.

I already did the first two steps. I don't have any idea of how to do the 3rd and 4th steps. Thanks in advance.

Here's the first HTML document: **form.html**

```
    <body>
<div align="center">
    <h1>TRIANGLE DRAWING</h1>
    <form action="drawing.php" method="post">
        <label>Type the value for triangle's size (big or small):</label>
        <input type="text" name="size" id="sizeVal">
        <br><br>
        <label>Type the number of cycles:</label>
        <input type="text" name="cycle" id="cycles">
        <br><br>
        <label>Choose your color:</label>
        <input type="color" name="selColor" value="#FFFFFF" id="ColorVal">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" id="c1" name="ready" value="Data OK">
    </form>
```

The second one, **drawing.php** (where the variables will be taken).

```
<?php

        //info
        echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Your DATA has been received");</script>';
        //capture values
        $size = $_REQUEST['size'];
        $cycle = $_REQUEST['cycle'];
        $color = $_REQUEST['selColor'];

        print("size is: $size");
        echo "<br>";
        print("cyclenum is: $cycle");
        echo "<br>";
        print("color is: $color");
        echo "<br><br>";
```

I don't know how to get the values SIZE, CYCLE AND COLOR and send them to another HTML page. 
In the new page, I want to draw a triangle with the size and color specified by the user (ignore cycle, for time reasons). I will use canvas and javascript to do it. Maybe the values in PHP could be passed to the javascript function directly?

Comment: a HTML file alone wouldn't be able to just receive values you would have to use JS or PHP for example **result.php** and use same as in the current make a **GET** redirection to **result.php** passing your values. or simply just generate you html through your **drawing.php**.  if you need to use the values in many places try using **SESSIONS**

Comment: Generate my HTML file through a PHP file? That means use include?

Comment: I think you forgot something very simple is that PHP can be used inside a HTML file so you can have drawing.php you final html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Setting a session for each Variable you want to transfer from page to page.

```
    <?php
    echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Your DATA has been received");</script>';
    $size = $_REQUEST['size'];
    $cycle = $_REQUEST['cycle'];
    $color = $_REQUEST['selColor'];
    $_SESSION['size'] = $size;
    $_SESSION['cycle'] = $cycle; 
    $_SESSION['color'] = $color;
    print("size is: $size");
    echo "<br>";
    print("cyclenum is: $cycle");
    echo "<br>";
    print("color is: $color");
    echo "<br><br>"; 
    ?>
```

On your next page

```
   <?php
   echo $_SESSION['size'] ;
   echo $_SESSION['cycle'] ; 
   echo $_SESSION['color'] ;
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using the PHP framework (e.g., laravel), the HTML file can be directly introduced with include. If the previous page does not use any template engine (such as: Smarty), use the < PHP?
Echo $size? > it should be ok

Comment: Where do I use <?php echo $size ?> in the new HTML page? inside a form?

Comment: Use it directly in the HTML page where you want to draw graphics (eg <div> <?php echo  $ size> </ div>) or in JS. In the same way, the page can parse PHP variables and try it yourself